# How do i implement section in core data for mac?

Tags: macos, core-data, nstableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

iOS provides `NSFetchedResultsController` class with sectioning support:

```
     NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
                 [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                             initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                             managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                             sectionNameKeyPath:@"CtoP.title"
                             cacheName:nil];
```

Core Data for Mac OS X doesn't provide an equivalent.

How can I implement sections for calendar days in my custom `NSTableView`?

Comment: Use a Sidebar control and look for the Apple Sidebar example

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTableView` doesn't have section support, so you have to build that yourself. On the desktop you'd use an `NSArrayController` to fetch from CoreData. You can simply sort by date and then use the day to create your own sections, but the main thing is to make the `NSTableView` class show something like a section.

Comment: I already create a custom NSTableView to display something like section,question is i am not familiar with core data ,how do i fetch data from core data and section data by day?

Comment: There's nothing 'magical' to sections. You just calculate an NSInteger from each item and that's the section. If you want to use bindings, use an NSArrayController, if not, set up an NSFetchRequest. Make sure to set the batch size to something reasonable if you use an NSFetchRequest.